# ParaView, VTK, Numpy and plot over line

Tags: python, numpy, vtk, paraview

I want to draw a timeline next to my animated glyph in ParaView. I am done with animating the glyph (*pfh*) and now I want to draw a grpah next to it, animated in the same time steps, I am reading in the VTU files ...

Basically I have an `x` and `y` value for every vtu file I load, I want to show in a plot over line.

I have the values in an numpy array, called `values`.

```
from vtk.util import numpy_support 
values = np.array((x,y))
vtk_values = numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(values, array_type=vtk.VTK_FLOAT)
vtk_values.setName('values_2_show')
vtk_values.setComponentName(1, 'x_value')
vtk_values.setComponentName(2, 'y_value')
```

and I have these values in ParaView now. Now I am stuck, on how I can add them to the plotOverLine. I do have the feeling I need to find a way to bring the external source into the pipe instead of using:

```
VTUFILE = FindSource('VTUFILE*')
plotOverLine1 = PlotOverLine(Input=VTUFILE, Source='High Resolution Line Source')
```

I also set the plotoverline options:

```
plotOverLine1.Tolerance = 2.22044604925031e-16
plotOverLine1.Source.Point1 = [0.0, 500.0, 3.0]
plotOverLine1.Source.Point2 = [1000.0, 500.0, 3.0]
lineChartView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('XYChartView')
plotOverLine1Display = Show(plotOverLine1, lineChartView1)
plotOverLine1Display.CompositeDataSetIndex = [0]
plotOverLine1Display.UseIndexForXAxis = 0
plotOverLine1Display.XArrayName = 'values_2_show'
plotOverLine1Display.SeriesVisibility = ['values_2_show']
plotOverLine1Display.SeriesLabel = ['values_2_show', 'values_2_show']
plotOverLine1Display.SeriesColor = ['values_2_show', '0.1', '0.89', '0.1']
plotOverLine1Display.SeriesPlotCorner = ['values_2_show', '0']
plotOverLine1Display.SeriesLineStyle = ['values_2_show', '1']
plotOverLine1Display.SeriesLineThickness = ['values_2_show', '2']
plotOverLine1Display.SeriesMarkerStyle = ['values_2_show', '0']
```

Comment: I am confused. Are you saying things are working when you save the values out as VTU files, but now you want to skip the step of having to save VTU files and directly do the numpy code in PAraView pipeline?

Comment: I have VTU files and a log file, that contains information for the VTUs I want to display. Imagine playing 100 VTUs in a line, showing a movement all together of a car and a plotoverline next to it that shows how many people are in the car at the given VTU